# Help with referring to sub-float figures?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, subfloats

I have six subfigures (i.e. Figure 1a, 1b, 1c, etc.) and I'd like to reference both the subfigures and the main figure (i.e. Figure 1), in the text. In this example, `\ref{fig: lattice_strain}` should refer to Figure 1, and `\ref{fig: Fe_Lat_Strain}` should be Figure 1a. Instead I get `[??]` appear in the body of the text. I'd appreciate any help!

Example:

```
Figure \ref{fig: lattice_strain} illustrates the change in the measured lattice strain with engineering strain and time for several Fe (\ref{fig: Fe_Lat_Strain}, M$_{23}$C$_{6}$ (\ref{fig: M_Lat_Strain}) and Nb(N, C) (\ref{fig: N_Lat_Strain} precipitate reflections in the loading direction.

\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont=bf}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{fig: Fe_Lat_Strain}\includegraphics[scale=1]{Fe_Lat_Strain}} 
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{fig: M_Lat_Strain}\includegraphics[scale=1]{M_Lat_Strain}} 
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{fig: N_Lat_Strain}\includegraphics[scale=1]{N_Lat_Strain}} 
\end{minipage}\par\smallskip
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{fig: Fe_Lat_Time}\includegraphics[scale=1]{Fe_Lat_Time}} 
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{fig: M_Lat_Time}\includegraphics[scale=1]{M_Lat_Time}} 
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{fig: N_Lat_Time}\includegraphics[scale=1]{N_Lat_Time}} 
\end{minipage}
\label{fig: lattice_strain}
\caption{(a--c)...(d-f)...} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. The `\label` always has to be placed *after* (or within) the `\caption`.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that mistake after submitting this

Answer (score 1):

In addition to following @TorbjørnT's advice and placing the `\label` instruction *after* the associated `\caption` instruction, you should look into simplifying the code considerably, e.g., by getting rid of the two `minipage` "wrappers" and by omitting all 6 `\centering` instructions. Next, set sensible (relative) widths for the images and separate the subfigures visually by issuing `\hfill` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
\begin{document}
Figure \ref{fig:lattice_strain} \dots 
(\ref{fig:Fe_Lat_Strain}), 
M$_{23}$C$_{6}$ (\ref{fig:M_Lat_Strain}), 
and Nb(N, C) (\ref{fig:N_Lat_Strain}) \dots

\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont=bf}

\subfloat[]{\label{fig:Fe_Lat_Strain}\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Fe_Lat_Strain}} 
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:M_Lat_Strain}\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{M_Lat_Strain}} 
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:N_Lat_Strain}\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{N_Lat_Strain}} 

\smallskip

\subfloat[]{\label{fig:Fe_Lat_Time}\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Fe_Lat_Time}} 
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:M_Lat_Time}\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{M_Lat_Time}} 
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:N_Lat_Time}\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{N_Lat_Time}} 

\caption{(a--c) \dots\ (d--f) \dots} 
\label{fig:lattice_strain}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```